# TDD to 'discover' attributes of a class?

Tags: java, tdd

I am trying a little TDD for the first time. I started with absolutely nothing and wrote some tests for a self written Date library.

I want to be able to do for example:

```
MyDate m = new MyDate(1,1,2012);
```

and assert that

`m.equals(new MyDate(2,1,2012))` is `false`.

Now with only these two items, I could write a constructor that simply doesn't do anything but still fulfills "being able to call the constructor with three ints to construct a date". And I could write an equals method that always returns `false`.

So far, I haven't written any attributes, although I'm preeeetty sure I want to have at least three of them, corresponding with the arguments of the constructor. Should I go on writing a test and then 'discover' these attributes as I go on? Or am I pushing it too hard and should I just write a basic class with the attributes I already know are needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to learn TDD *well*, I suggest you to do it by the book.  Write a little test, see it fail, make it pass, remove duplication, repeat.  Even before this, you should write a little list of all the tests that you think you will need to write.  This is the kind of "thinking ahead" that works well with TDD.  You will come back to this list to cross off the tests that you made pass, and to add new tests that occur to you while you work.

I suggest you not to try variations on this process before you have learned it :-)

Your little test is good enough; you must make it *fail* first by writing an equals method that returns true.  Then you make it pass, then you write anther test that proves that two dates can be equal if they have the same attributes.  It will take you only a few minutes.

Good luck!

Comment: Before you can break the rules, you must be able to follow them.

Comment: But rather than making it fail by writing equals() to return true, you could write a test (as @RCE says) that fails in the default case; this test would drive you more directly to an equals method, then the test that needs false from equals() would drive a more complete equals() method.

Answer (score 2):

Optimally equal would always return false *if* you have only that one test.

You know there will be other test cases and writing that `return false` is waste of time. You should write few more tests so you can actually write working code other than `return false`.

For example with

```
MyDate m = new MyDate(1,1,2012);
assertTrue(m.equals(new MyDate(1,1,2012)));
```

and

```
MyDate m = new MyDate(1,1,2012);
assertFalse(m.equals(new MyDate(2,1,2012)));
```

you can actually write some *real* code for comparing the day value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider writing a few other tests first -

```
[Test] 
public void ANewlyConstructedMyDateHasCorrectYear(){
  Assert.AreEqual(2012, new MyDate(2, 1, 2012).Year);
}
```

for instance - and then eventually move on to make sure your Equals method does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You shall start writing  other tests, defining what you expect from this class.  I do this step by step, alternating between  test code and real code  ( write test case, satisfy this,
write another ).  Sometimes I just do not have clue how to achieve something,   and algorithm
emerges while satisfying test cases.

Another useful technique is mocking; I prefer jMockit  as most powerful toolkit at the moment.  Here is an example of test driven development:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/test/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/PreferenceInjectionTest.java

Answer (score 0):

> So far, I haven't written any attributes, although I'm preeeetty sure I want to have at least three of them, corresponding with the arguments of the constructor. Should I go on writing a test and then 'discover' these attributes as
>   I go on?

Ultra-orthodox TDD says yes, you must not write any production code unless you have a failing test which needs that code to pass.

But there's a school of thought (Reform TDD, if you will) that says it's allowable to have thoughts about design that are not driven by tests. Following that school, it would be fine to design the interface (perhaps partially) of your class before writing any tests, then write some tests, then add implementation to make them work and while doing so perhaps refactor the interface.

Try it and see what works best for you.

Comment: I don't know of any TDD practitioner who says you can't **think** about the design before writing tests; in fact, one's thoughts about the design are the main **source** of tests. The TDD discipline is to not write any **code** without tests, and to write those tests one at a time.

Comment: @Edmund Schweppe: OK, so you're allowed to think about design as much as you want, but you're not allowed to act on that thinking except through tests and then only one tiny increment at a time. Which seems to me either a bizarre and harmful restriction or an attempt to promote detailed up-front UML designs. I guess this depends on whether one prefers to think about design abstractly or in the form of code interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You have a test suite (with one test) and some production code, and the production code passes all the tests. This is the "green" phase of the TDD red-green-refactor lifecycle.

Since you started with a test of `equals()`, I'd recommend writing another test to assert that `date1.equals(date1)` returns `true`. This will obviously fail if your `equals()` method always returns `false`, and that will drive a "real" implementation of `equals()`. On the other hand, if you're more concerned about knowing what year a `new MyDate(2, 1, 2012)` represents, you could write a test asserting that it has a Year attribute with a value of 2012. Which test you write first depends on what you as the designer and developer of the code are most concerned with at that moment.

You want to **avoid** the nasty temptation of coding a bunch of tests at once - doing so means you spend lots of extra time in the "red" phase, where you don't know that the code works because you've got failing tests.

Comment: Except that it's merely an illusion of working code, and wasting time writing non-functional code just to keep that illusion intact at all times seems to me pretty pointless. So I'll wholeheartedly submit to that nasty temptation.